# Sequence is Cauchy in one metric and not in another metric which both determine the same topology on a set $X$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to figure out a case where for some set $X$ and two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ which determine the same topology, but a sequence is Cauchy in one but not the other.

My idea was to take the interval $X= (- \pi, \pi)$, with $d_1$ being the euclidean metric. Then there exists a natural homeomorphism $f\colon X \rightarrow X_2$ where $X_2$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the point $(0,-1)$ removed, and the metric $d_2$ to be the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is even and $1- \frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is odd. This should be Cauchy in $X_2$ as the points are getting closer together as it tends to infinity, but the points grow further apart in $X$ for this sequence.

Is this correct? And if not, would someone be able to point to my mistake, or a simpler way of solving this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Seems like it works to me.  You could also map the interval to the full real line and take a sequence approaching infinity on the real line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence in your example is not a Cauchy sequence in $(-\pi,\pi)$. You have probably in mind choosing values $-\pi+\frac1n$ and $\pi-\frac1n$.

But there is a very natural example: $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and ${\bf R}$ are homeomorphic,  a sequence, say, $\pi/2-1/n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ with the Euclidean metric, but its image is not a Cauchy sequence in $\bf R$ with the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response! So the map you are talking about is $tan(x)$. I do not see why $\pi/2 - 1/n$ is not cauchy in \mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean metric, as it converges in $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore must be cauchy.

Comment: @laura Not $\pi/2-1/n$, but its image. $\tan(\pi/2-1/n)$ tends to infinity, hence not near all elements are in a set of diameter $\epsilon$. However, Euclidean metric induces the same topology as that of an open interval.

Comment: oh yes, that makes sense! The metric $d_2$ for $(- \pi/2, \pi/2)$ would just be $d_2(x,y) = d (tan(x), tan(y))$ then? Where $d$ is the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @laura Near, in the sense: $d$ on the interval and $d_2$ on $\bf R$. And now the same $d$, but on $\bf R$, and $d_2$ generate the same topology on $\bf R$.